# C++ : Run Code Error with EOF ( End-Of-File )

Tags: visual-c++, eof

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 to run the following code but i get an error. Can anyone tell me what is the problem ?

C++ Code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    while ((cin >> a >> b) != EOF)
    {
        cout << "Sum is: " << a + b << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: whats the error?

Answer (score -1):

Most likely issue is the EOF - the >> operator returns a reference to a stream object - not return an integer like EOF

just using tis may work ok - it will continue until a fail bit is set.

```
while (cin >> a >> b)
```